# Values are nil for form submission (param is missing or the value is empty: amount)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, routes

I am a newbie with rails so forgive me. I know I am getting this error because I specified that amount be required for the parameters. If I did not, I end up with a transaction entry with just a transaction_id with every other field being nil. I believe my problem has to deal with my routes, but I'm not sure whats wrong.

My error:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in TransactionsController#create
>
> param is missing or the value is empty: amount

But I can see that the fields are being passed:

```
     Parameters:
      {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>
"H+Xxpze7HWC9oduZC2CSxnWHztfhabEMRCoYy0Gw7upNknF2aIHsZ1G/xQOsICTVd7n4btqtT5760UL7QovIrA==",
"transaction"=>{"amount"=>"29", "transactionType"=>"withdraw"}, "commit"=>"Create Transaction"}
```

My TransactionsController:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @account = Account.find(params[:account_id]) 
    @transaction = Transaction.new
    @transaction.account_id = @account.id
end

def create 
   @transaction = Transaction.new(transactions_params)
    if @transaction.save
       redirect_to '/viewAccount/:id'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private 
def transactions_params 
    params.require(:amount).permit(:account_id, :transactionType) 
end
end
```

My New View (form):

```
<div class="destination">
<div class="container">
<div class = "form">
<h3>Add a new transaction for <%= current_user.email %> </h3>
<%= form_for(@transaction) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>
  <%= f.select :transactionType, [['withdraw', 'withdraw'], ['deposit', 'deposit']] %>
  <%= f.submit "Create Transaction", class: "btn-submit" %>
<% end %> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'mysite#index'
get 'signup' => 'users#new'
post 'signup' => 'users#create'
resources :users
get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
get'newAccount' => 'accounts#new'
get 'viewAccount/:id' => 'banksite#show'
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
get 'transactions' => 'transactions#new'
post 'transactions' => "transactions#create"
resources :transactions
```

Banking View/start of transactions new

```
<div class=content>
<div class=main>
<h1>Welcome to Online Banking <%= current_user.email %></h1>
<p>You're only allowed to see this page if you are logged in</p>
    <h2><%= current_user.email %> 's Account Summary</h2>
    <h3>Balance: $ <%= @account.balance %> </h3>
   <%= link_to "Create Transaction", 
:controller => "transactions", 
:action => "new", 
:account_id => @account.id %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_one :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

I would appreciate any insight into this error.

Comment: I believe your `resources :transactions` is blowing out your custom `post`. Try removing the `get` and `post` on transactions, and just use the `resources :transactions` line. That line should create all the methods for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
params.require(:amount).permit(:account_id, :transactionType)
```

is expecting parameters like:

```
"amount" => { "account_id" => "...", "transactionType" => "..." }
```

but your parameters look like:

```
"transaction"=>{"amount"=>"29", "transactionType"=>"withdraw"}
```

Also, there is no `account_id` in your form.

First you'll need to get `account_id` into your form with something like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :account_id %>
```

Then you need to update your form parsing in your controller with something like:

```
params.require(:transaction).permit(:account_id, :amount, :transactionType)
```

so that it will be looking for `"transaction"` at the top level and `"account_id"`, `"amount"`, and `"transactionType"` inside that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and speedy reply! Its working well now!